# Limit of $\sqrt{x-x^2}$ as $x$ approaches $1$

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm certain that the result is 0, but my book does not quite agree with me, infact it says that the limit is undefined, is the book wrong? Looking at the domain of f it should be correct supposing the limit as 0.. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The limit typically implies that both directions are to be evaluated.  What happens when this limit is considered as $x\to 1^+$?

Comment: I believe that your book is wrong. The function is not defined for $x>1$ and therefore you need only consider the limit as $x$ approaches $1$ from below. Therefore indeed the limit is equal to 0 and not undefined. Bad example in my opinion, but perhaps I am wrong.

Comment: It's impossible to answer this question unless you say *exactly* what definition of limit your book is using. With the definition of limit that we teach in the calculus courses at our department, the limit *does* exist (and equals zero), but other sources may have a different opinion.

Comment: The same old |f(x)-L|<e, assuming e>0 and is a real number, when limit f(x)=L as x-->x* ,where x* is a real number.
Verifing by this i found that the answer given by the book is correct... We're using Calculus: Single Variable by R.Adams

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume $$\lim_{x\to 1}\sqrt{x-x^2}=0.$$
Then, $$\lim_{x\to 1^+}\sqrt{x-x^2}=\lim_{x\to 1^-}\sqrt{x-x^2}=0.$$
But noting $$\sqrt{x-x^2}=\sqrt{x(1-x)}$$  we have that for $x> 1$, $x(1-x)$ is negative, and thus $\sqrt{x(1-x)}$ is not a real number.

As a result, $\lim_{x\to 1^+}\sqrt{x-x^2}$ does not exist in $\mathbb{R}$, and so the same goes for $\lim_{x\to 1}\sqrt{x-x^2}.$

Answer (score 1):

No, your book is not wrong.. x approaches to 1, that means x can be approach to 1 either from left side or right side. Let, x approaches from right side. i.e. $x>1$, and then $x<x^2$ and so $x-x^2<0$, so $\sqrt {x-x^2}$ doesn't exists, so limit won't exist. But if x approaches to 1 from left side, i.e. $x<1$, then limit will be $0$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x\to1^-}\sqrt{x-x^2}=0$$

as expected.  But taking $\epsilon\gt 0$, we have $x=1+\epsilon\implies x-x^2=1+\epsilon-1-2\epsilon-\epsilon^2=-\epsilon-\epsilon^2,$ which is always negative for $\epsilon\gt 0$.  Taking the square root of such a number results in a non-real number quantity and is therefore outside the range of the function.